# How can I better compress my swf file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a fairly simple flash ad that I have created. The swf file is currently 119kb, and I need to compress it to 40kb.

There is only one image in the file and it is only 5kb, everything else is saved as symbols containing mostly small amounts of text and a couple simple shapes.
There are minimal amount of keyframes and animations are done with classic alpha channel tweens.
I am embedding 30 character from a font. I tried removing the font and it only saved me 15kb.

what else can I do to save space?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working on Flash Advertising and trying to meet publisher specifications. This is a problem I face as well (though not too often now that we have another developer to do this while I focus on applications and sites).

Something that will really help you is generating a size report. This will detail all the elements consuming file size and exactly how much. It can be turned on via `File => Publish Settings`:

[image]

It will give you something like this in the output window when you run a test, as well as generating a text file with the same content:

```
TEC001_300x600.swf Movie Report
--------------------------------

Frame #    Frame Bytes    Total Bytes    Scene
-------    -----------    -----------    -----
      1          22102          22102    Scene 1 (AS 3.0 Classes Export Frame)
      2           9908          32010    

Scene      Shape Bytes    Text Bytes    ActionScript Bytes
-------    -----------    ----------    ------------------
Scene 1             63             0                 11097

Symbol                 Shape Bytes    Text Bytes    ActionScript Bytes
-------------------    -----------    ----------    ------------------
Copy4.1                          0            57                     0
Copy4.2                          0            49                     0
Copy4.3                          0            44                     0
Copy4.4                          0            41                     0
CTA                             42            58                     0
Panel                           93           265                     0
SubmitButton                   182            82                     0
Text1.1                          0            36                     0
Text1.2                          0            32                     0
Text2.1                          0            34                     0
Text2.2                          0            39                     0
Text3.1                          0            42                     0
Text3.2                          0            38                     0
Clickthrough.Button             30             0                     0
Final                           30             0                     0
Path 3                          86             0                     0

Font Name                 Bytes         Characters
----------------------    ----------    ----------
OfficinaSans-Bold Bold         10150     '-.0123456789@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 

ActionScript Bytes    Location
------------------    --------
             11097    Scene 1:Frame 1

Bitmap            Compressed    Original      Compression
--------------    ----------    ----------    -----------
background.jpg          5647        720000    Imported JPEG=102
logo.png                 759          5304    Lossless
```